# How to opimize user defined python functions handling millions of rows?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using python 3.6.
My Python code is retrieving data from a database, and processing the data and saving the result in csv format. After processing, I'm getting around 80 million rows.

One field of the processed data is a value of a dictionary, and that field contains multiple value against the key; so during processing, that field's values are stored in a data frame column in list format.

I need to replace that value with the corresponding dictionary key. So I wrote the following function for converting the value to a dictionary key:

```
def keysWithValue(aDict, target):
    return sorted(key for key, value in aDict.items() if target == value)
```

I'm feeling that if I will use a `for` loop for those 80 million records and call this function on each of them, it will take lots of time. Can you please suggest me some alternative Python approach instead of modifying it directly in my database that will save my code running time?

Comment: Do you know which column you should check against your dictionary? Or you have to check every single column for 80M rows?

Comment: Yes zwer, I know which column to check

Comment: In memory processing is great for reasonably big data. You don't give the total size of one row, but 80 million rows seem big enough to use sqlite3 database that support indexing. The good news is that you are no longer limited by the available memory.

Comment: Sorry Serge, I'm not getting. What's the solution?

Comment: You don't explain what the actions are in "retrieving data from database & processing the data" - it sounds like you should look if what you're trying to do here would be better moved into your DB extract or the immediately following stage... For instance, you might be able to get the DB to output the key and value, ordered by the key, you could then group by accordingly DB side or if needed during processing side using `itertools.groupby` depending on what you want... (or heck, maybe even just shove it into a key/value store depending what it's needed for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a reverse lookup dictionary for that field:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def makeInverseLookupDict(aDict):
    reverseDict = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in aDict.iteritems():
        reverseDict[value].append(key)

    return reverseDict
```

Finding the keys with the given value is now O(1). This will take up as much space as the original dict, but will be instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest you're going to get is to reverse the keys and values to create a value:key lookup map:

```
rev_dict = {v: k for k, v in aDict.items()}  # use aDict.iteritems() on Python 2.x
```

**UPDATE** - if there isn't a 1-to-1 relationship between the key and the value and you have multiple values instead, you can unpack them as:

```
rev_dict = {i: k for k, v in aDict.items() for i in v}  # use aDict.iteritems() on Python 2.x
```

Then in your code, when you retrieve the data from your DB, just grab the column value by looking through that lookup map:

```
column_value = rev_dict.get(column_value, column_value)
```

Which will give you the key if `column_value` exists in `aDict` or will return it's own value unchanged.

Keep in mind, tho, that if your `aDict` isn't too big, while your approach is a bit wasteful most of the time to process those 80M rows would still be spent on I/O operations.

Comment: Hi Zwer, thanks for the solution. But I'm not getting that field,let's say 'A' , from database.It's generated during processing & also one portion was missing in my original post, which I have added now in my post, after processing my records are stored in a data frame where that Field A has multiple value against key. So Field  A is stored as a list in data frame. In that case will your solution work ?

Comment: @PythonLearner - you can further unpack values to point to the same key, check the update above. If that doesn't solve your problem you could take some time to actually explain your structure as it's certainly not clear from your question.